# Unable to open Spring source tool suite

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I installed `SpringSource Tool Suite` after which I was alerted that I hadn't set the `JAVA_HOME`. The installation was successful by then, so I closed the suite and set the java_home.

But now I don't find any way to open the suite. No shortcut in desktop or start menu.

How to open it?
Or should I re-install it?

Comment: which is the OS used? do you remember installation directory

Comment: @ArunPJohny Windows 7. Yes I remember the installation directory

Comment: in the installation directory you have STS.exe file

Comment: or in the `start > search program and files` type `spring` then in the  results you will find `Spring Tool Suit`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you. Oh yeah, its working. How stupid of me. I tried and its working. I think I will flag this question myself and delete it. Shall I?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that you can accept it

Comment: I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows 7 go to `Start > search program and files` and type `spring` then in the results you will find `Spring Tool Suit`.

Else if you remember the installation path, to there you can find the `STS.exe` file

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, was unable to open STS because of the Lombok path .inc file of STS.
remove the path and start.
**Suggestion**
if you added some external project like Lombok and did not install properly and you removed that project due to some reason then you must remove the path from the inc STS file.